# Sort an observable collection of type T where T will change on run time (generics)

Tags: c#, generics, observablecollection

Hello I want to sort an ObservableCollection but I cant get access to its properties.

```
public static class CommonMethods<T> 
{
    public static ObservableCollection<T> Sort(ObservableCollection<T> array, string columnName, bool sort) 
    {
        ObservableCollection<T> res = new ObservableCollection<T>();
        res = res.OrderBy(r => r[""]) // This gives an error says cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type T.
        return res;
    }
}
```

The Calling code.

```
mlRegionDetails = CommonMethods<MLRegion>.Sort(mlRegionDetails, columnName, sort);
```

Please do tell me where I m going wrong.

Comment: You need generic constraint which indicates what `T` can be. E.g. a specific interface? Or any class? A struct? We don´t know. Btw: why do you create a new collection that doesn´t contain *any* elements? I suppose you want to order the input-collection, don´t you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i found an alternate solution to the problem. I create a temp var then convert that ObservableCollection to AsEnumerable and ordering it by the Key passed to it.

Creating key part credit goes to @Camilo Terevinto

```
public static class CommonMethods
{
    public static ObservableCollection<T> sort<T>(ObservableCollection<T> array, Func<T, object> key)
    {
        var res = array.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(key); ;
        ObservableCollection<T> temp = new ObservableCollection<T>(res);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing the name of the property you want to order by, pass the selector function:

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> Sort(ObservableCollection<T> array, Func<T, object> columnSelector, bool sort) 
{
    ObservableCollection<T> res = new ObservableCollection<T>(array.OrderBy(columnSelector));
    return res;
}
```

And call it using this:

```
mlRegionDetails = CommonMethods<MLRegion>.Sort(mlRegionDetails, x => x.SomeColumn, sort);
```

If you want to do this using `string`s, you will need to build the expression manually.

*Note*: the following code has not been tested as it was written here, it may need some change.

```
public static class CommonMethods<T> 
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo orderByMethod =
        typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(method =>
            method.Name == nameof(Enumerable.OrderBy) && method.GetParameters().Length == 2);

    public static ObservableCollection<T> Sort(ObservableCollection<T> array, string columnName, bool sort) 
    {
        var tType = typeof(T);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(tType);

        Expression member = Expression.Property(parameter, columnName);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(member, paramter);

        var genericMethod = orderByMethod.MakeGenericMethod(tType, member.Type);

        var orderedData = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { array, lambda }) as IEnumerable<T>;

        return new ObservableCollection<T>(orderedData);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i build the expression

Comment: @RohanSampat I have added an example

Comment: I tries your solution of Func<T, object> columnSelector which you gave me first but  when I pass the column selector to OrderBy, it says Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<T>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @RohanSampat That was a problem in your original code, I have fixed that now

Comment: I tried your second method of creating expression of string but it breaks on generic.Invoke line saying  - Object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[ConsoleApp1.Entity.Company,System.Int32]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Func`2[ConsoleApp1.Entity.Company,System.Int32]

Comment: I tried another work around with the help of your Key creation part.